# Using Clone() with polymorphism from interface in java

Tags: java

I am having problems trying to figure out how to call the clone method from a object which its reference is of an interface type.

Basically this is what I need to do.

```
for(Interface obj: objs)
array.add(obj.clone());
```

I do not know what is the obj type, I just know it implements Interface, and when I try this code I get

"The method clone() is undefined for the type Interface".

And when I try to put clone() on my Interface I get:

"The method clone() of type Interface must override or implement a supertype method", because I am using @Override tag.

My intention is to use Object.clone() in the end. But I just cant figure this out.

Any thoughts?

The real code:

```
 public interface Caracteristica {
    @Override <---problem
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;

    @Override <---fine
public boolean equals(Object obj);
 }

 private final void setCaracteristicas(ArrayList<Caracteristica> caracteristicas) {
    this.caracteristicas = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Caracteristica caracteristica: caracteristicas)
        this.caracteristicas.add((Caracteristica)caracteristica.clone());
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `clone()` and the `Cloneable` interface is broken in a number of ways and even according to Josh Bloch it should be avoided. (See: http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Add a new method to your interface that returns the interface type and implement that in your class to make copies.

**Edit to Add:** Ignoring the above statement, the reason it is telling you that the `@Override` annotation in your interface is incorrect is because ... it is. You're not extending an interface that defines `clone()`.

Interfaces don't extend `Object`; [Section 9.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2) tells us:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

`clone()` is `protected` in `Object` so it is not implicitly included. If your IDE said to add the `@Override` tag, report that as a bug, because it's wrong.

`equals()`, on the other hand, is `public` in `Object`, therefore it is included in the implicit superinterface unless you override it.

If you are bound and determined, this will *work* though it's really ugly due to the confusion created by `clone()` being defined both in `Object` and `MyInterface` and having it return the interface type (which is allowed because it's a covariant type):

```
public interface MyInterface {
    MyInterface clone();
    void doSomething();
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

    @Override
    public MyInterface clone() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInterface mi = new MyClass();
        MyInterface mi2 = mi.clone();
        mi2.doSomething();
    }

}
```

Comment: I know. My problem is not "it is a bad idea or not" is just "do"

Comment: So the problem was just a bug...I can live with that. and yep, it seems that there is no way out, as you say, it is ugly... that is what we get for using clone() I guess...

Comment: I have just read your edit. I know the tag incorrect: even semantically. But any way, I got curious about why in one method is fine and the other it is not. I guess it is just a bug. Thanks any way.

Comment: `equals()` *is* overriden. It's a public method in `Object` so it's in the implicit interface superclass.

Comment: Personally, I find it weird/confusing not having an explicit superclass like you do with `Object`, but they didn't ask for my opinion in 1994 :-D

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) is `protected`, you can't call it from outside the class or its subclasses unless they explicitly change the access modifier to `public` thus there is no guarantee an object has a visible `clone()` method.

You have to define this in an interface or override it in a baseclass instead.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose there is no harm on doing that. I am curious though: How can I do ( @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj)) but not (@Override public Object clone();)?

Comment: Erm, you certainly can call it from subclasses that declare it public. `int[] newArray = oldArray.clone();` (That's pretty much the *only* time to use `clone()` though)

Comment: @BrianRoach: fair enough, you can change it to `public`. But this doesn't apply here as far as I can see: he's talking about iterating over interface implementations so there is no changed modifier. I've added it to the answer though, for completeness.

Comment: @VictorSoares: you can. Just type in `clone` and your IDE will probably offer to complete it for you. Afterwards you have to change `protected` to `public`.

Comment: I did that, and the IDE did exactly what I did, and works fine but complains about the @Override tag, that the IDE itself put there.

Comment: I put the real code there - some stuff are in another language though.